# Juptyer Kernel Gateway CROS

Tags: python-3.x, http, cross-domain, jupyter, api-gateway

I have a Jupyter KernelGatewayApp running on a VM instance in Google cloud. I defined an API which responds to a GET statement.
If I combine the ip address of the VM instance with the port of the Kernel Gateway and the GET statement with the right parameters, I get the desired result.
However, I would like to call the API using a javascript button on another site. This doesn't work as the browser is first sending an OPTIONS statement which I don't manage to respond to correctly.

Concretely, I have the following:

Running Jupyter Kernel Gateway on port 8888 : 33.44.567.789:8888
Working API : 33.44.567.789:8888/api?fname=john&lname=doe
Other website where a javascript button calls the above API : johndoe.me

Returns following error on requestor (browser) side:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://33.44.567.789:8888/api?fname=john&lname=doe. Request header
>   field Content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response.

Generates following message on server:

> INFO:tornado.access:200 OPTIONS /api?fname=john&lname=doe
>   (xx.xxx.xx.xxx) 1.2 ms

Because of the thing I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) I added all different sort of parameters when launching the Jupyter Kernel Gateway:

```
jupyter kernelgateway --KernelGatewayApp.api='kernel_gateway.notebook_http' --KernelGatewayApp.seed_uri='/home/dummy_gmail_com/code/test_api.ipynb' --KernelGatewayApp.allow_origin='http://johndoe.me' --KernelGatewayApp.allow_methods='GET,OPTIONS,POST' --KernelGatewayApp.allow_credentials='true' --KernelGateway.allow_headers='Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, content-type' --KernelGatewayApp.expose_headers='Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,Accept' --KernelGatewayApp.answer_yes=True
```

The issue seems to be that the browser is issuing an OPTIONS instead of a GET but I'm not really sure. Is this linked to the cross origin fact ? Is there a way to handle this correctly or a way around this ?

Comment: The OPTIONS request comes from what is know as the browser pre-flight request.  The browser uses it to make sure the cross origin request will not cause trouble to old servers.  KernelGateway seems to handle it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Having had the same problem I found that CORS requests served by Jupyter Kernel Gateway worked with the following parameters:

```
jupyter kernelgateway --KernelGatewayApp.api='kernel_gateway.notebook_http' --KernelGatewayApp.seed_uri='/home/dummy_gmail_com/code/test_api.ipynb' --KernelGatewayApp.allow_origin='http://johndoe.me'
```

(Using OP's domains etc. for consistency.)

The parameter `KernelGatewayApp.allow_origin='*'` also worked/Solved the problem.

However I did go wrong prompted by the initial browser console error message which ran:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8889/convert?degrees=164' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to 
fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

This prompted me to set the request mode to `'no-cors'`.  The effect of this is to prevent an `Origin` header being sent with the request.  Under these circumstances no amount of tinkering with the kernel gateway parameters resulted in a successful response.

Also when specifying the Allow Origin header as anything other than `'*'` it needs to be an exact string match to the 'Origin' header.  For example:

`Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1` does not match `Origin: http://localhost`

`Allow-Origin: localhost` does not match `Origin: http://localhost`

`Allow-Origin: http://localhost/` does not match `Origin: http://localhost`

`Allow-Origin: http://localhost` does not match `Origin: http://localhost:3000`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

as you can see with service /siteupdate, you can allow origin on a per service basis